# How can I adjust the size of my "SpaceShip" sprite given the size code I have for it already?

Tags: python

I have some code to display a background and a sprite. However, I'm not exactly sure what the size and width and height part do for my sprite. Additionally, I'm not sure how to adjust the size of my sprite given what I have?

```
import pygame
pygame.init()



#screen setup 
screen_width = 700
screen_height = 700
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))

pygame.display.set_caption("game")

background = pygame.image.load("Space.jpeg")
background = pygame.transform.scale(background,(700,700))



sprite = pygame.image.load("SpaceShip.png")
sprite_size = sprite.get_rect().size
sprite_width = sprite_size[0]
sprite_height = sprite_size[1]



sprite_x = 200
sprite_y = 200
```

Comment: maybe better resize image in some paint editor (like `Photoshop`, `GIMP`) and don't do this in code. Image resized in paint editor can look better

Comment: how about `sprite = pygame.transform.scale(sprite,(sprite_width*2,sprite_height*2))` to double size of sprite

Comment: frankly, in most code you don't have to use directly `width` and `height` because `get_rect()` gives object `Rect()` which has `rect.right` instead of `rect.x + rect.width`, and `rect.bottom` instead of `rect.y + rect.height`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code after you first load your sprite if you want a specific image size:

```
desiredWidth = 256
desiredHeight = 256
sprite = pygame.transform.scale(sprite, (desiredWidth, desiredHeight))
```

Alternatively, you can use `pygame.transform.scale_by()` to scale by a constant, such as doubling in size.

If you want to get the width or height of an image, you can use `sprite.get_width()` directly without needing to first use `get_rect()`.

It is usually a good idea to scale your sprites in an external program, since pygame scaling is quite performance intensive and may not look particularly nice. ([This](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.smoothscale_by) may work better but I haven't tried it)